Name/property for the following sequence
Consider a sequence as follows: we have $a_0 = m$, where m is a positive integer. Then $a_1 = 1+...+m$, $a_2 = 1+(1+2)+...+(1+...+m)$, $a3 = 1+1+(1+2)+...+(1+...+m)$, etc.
So the iteration is like the following: if $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{t}x_k$ then $a_{n+1} = \sum_{k=1}^{t}(1+2+...+x_k)$
Is there any property, like growth rate or closed form expression for this sequence?

For example, if $a_0= 3$, what would the first few terms of $a_n$ be?

@peterwhy a1 = 1+2+3, a2 = 1+1+2+1+2+3, a3 = 1+1+1+2+1+1+2+1+2+3, etc. The exact formula is given in the answer below.

Does $a_2$ depend on how one partitions the summands of $a_1$? By the iteration rule, if $a_1 = \sum_{k=1}^6 1$ then $a_2 = \sum_{k=1}^6 1 = 6$. But if $a_1 = \sum_{k=1}^1 6$ then $a_2 = \sum_{k=1}^1 (1+2+\cdots+ 6) = 21$.

A name might be something like "iterated cumulative sums". But in fact there's a very simply closed form expression, which you can prove by induction on $k$:
$$
a_k = \binom{m + k - 1}k.
$$

This is indeed correct. But it's working "backward" for me in a sense. $a_k$ is the order polynomial $\Omega(P, m)$of a chain of k elements. What I want is actually order polynomials of none-chains by adding points recursively to the chain. Are you aware of any properties in that direction?

sorry, I don't understand the terms you're using
